# Creating a programmable gain amplifier with a digital pot and an op amp

Tags: amplifier, gain

I wanted to create a PGA using a single supply op amp and digital pot. I hooked up my circuit like below, but my signal is getting attenuated with Rwb = 200 ohm and Rf = 1k. Are there any problems with my setup?

[image]

Comment: What digital pot are you using? Some of them are +/- 20%. Also, what is Cin and the input signal?

Comment: I'm using MCP4561. Cin is 1uf ac coupling cap, the signal is 1.2Vpp, measured after Cin, the output is ~0.2Vpp. Rwb is measured to be 200 ohm.

Comment: Cin and Rwb form a (variable) low pass filter. If you have values of both components, you can calculate its crossover frequency and attenuation at your test frequency.

Answer (score 2):

What are you driving it with? With the inverting configuration the input impedance equals Rin, so the input impedance will only be 200Ω. This means unless your source is pretty low impedance (e.g. <20Ω) it will be noticeably attenuated.
Also, make sure you are using the digital pot correctly (I haven't checked how it works) by swapping it with a fixed 200Ω resistor - if it works okay like this then it must be something to do with the pot setup.

Comment: It's the output of a active BPF (so an op amp). That's probably it, though. I was hoping to be able to attenuate the signal in software using a digital pot but obviously if the input impedance goes too low then the signal itself becomes attenuated. I should've wired the pot in the feedback path.